# Textbox of editorfor htmlhelper is different for integer type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using to Editorfor for displaying values of a class in the view. I am using MVC .  While the textbox properties and appearance are the same for values of string type, the textbox appearance for value of integer is changed and not consistence with the other textbox appearances. 
I have uploaded a snap of the view as well as the code.

```
  <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "Project Id", new { @class = "control-label" })
            </td>
            <td>

                    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Id)

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Project Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA3zB.png)

Comment: Because `EditorFor()` add `type="number"` for `int`, and `type="text"` for `string`

Comment: @StephenMuecke    How to change the appearance to keep in consistence with the other textboxes. I tried overriding the type as text. It still did not help.

Comment: I have no idea what your css is, but you could start by using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi, I tried TextBoxfor=> , all it did was increase the size of the textbox. Is there any work-around? like converting the int type to string in the view.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it - Its a styling issue - i.e. your css (and you have not shown any of it!) And tables are for tabular data, NOT layout

Comment: And your `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })` certainly will not add the `readonly` attribute so its clear you have not even shown the correct code

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi, the read-only property is working fine. The text-box is non-editable. And I assure you that i have shown a snippet of the exact code.

Comment: Nonsense. If you are claiming that your code adds the `readonly` attribute then you are mistaken - the format is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly"" } })` (and it only works for MVC-5.1 or higher - prior to that you could not add html attributes using `EditorFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey man, you don't have to be rude. I am just asking for help. I wouldn't ask for help without sharing the snippet of exact code. And I am using MVC 5.2 version. If I needed help on the readonly property I would have asked. If you can't help me then the least you can do is be nice and let someone else help.

Comment: No one can help you - styling is a css issue and you have not shown it or the html you are generating (and you have not shown the relevant code  - which I assue is a custom `EditorTemplate` - since what you have shown does not do what your image shows)

Comment: <input name="Id" class="text-box single-line" id="Id" style="background-color: lightgray;" type="number" readonly="" value="1847" data-val-required="The Id field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number.">

Comment: @StephenMuecke FYI the readonly property is controlled by scripts in the view but I need help with the textbox. I have added the generated Html code.

Comment: [edit] your question to add additional details instead of squeezing them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried going through the files to find the exact styling, but couldn't afford to spend too much time searching as the CSS file contained the code in a single line (to reduce size of the file). I however worked out a work-around by adding a string variable to the same class and assigning the integer value before passing the model to the view.